# On writing the below code in Robot file, for ${i} I am getting "Variable definition not found"

Tags: robotframework, variable-assignment

```
@{List1}=    Create List    a    b    c    f
FOR    ${i}    IN    @{List1}
    Log    ${i}
END
```

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/957iP.png):

Comment: FOR and END lines should be aligned with the first line, other that that, the code seems to work just fine

Comment: This code works perfectly fine for me. Please provide a complete [mcve] that actually illustrates the problem. This looks like a bug in your robot plugin for whatever editor you're using. It's not a problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of an incomplete question.

When we look at the screenshot, we can see that the question is related with IDE or Editor mentioning that the variable `${i}` is not defined.

For future questions, always provide textual information, and as much as possible (better surplus info than missing).